# Cross server SSIS automated extract with dynamic tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis, extract

You'll have to forgive my ignorance on this - I'm generally a one server kind of guy!

I have a live and reporting server we'll call `LIVE` and `REP`.

I have a set of tables on `LIVE`, some data from which needs to be `PIVOT`ted **every night** onto the `REP` server. This already happens through a SSIS package - trouble is - **the extract script is fixed* but *I need it to be dynamic*.

ie. I need to have a new table on `LIVE` which defines what exactly is extracted to `REP`.

This means that I want to

- DROP the extracted tables on `REP` every night
- CREATE the new tables on `REP` as defined in the `LIVE` table
- Build dynamic SQL to SELECT from the `LIVE` tables into the newly created `REP` tables

I'm concerned because I know SSIS can be funny about table definitions etc etc.

**I'm not asking about how to build the dynamic SQL** - I've already done that part, and it runs fine entirely on `LIVE` - but it needs to be cross-server.

Has anyone ever done this before? What is the best practice? Am I even allowed to `EXEC` dynamic SQL within a SSIS package, and can this be scheduled?

Comment: What part of it is not cross server? If you have built dynamic SQL you can execute that SQL using different connection (via connection manager).

Comment: Well the SELECT I have built needs to pull from `LIVE` and populate tables in `REP`...

Answer (score 2):

This might give you some ideas:

Create main workflow where you construct drop tables dynamically and create list of tables by creating a result set:

[image: Main Workflow]

Setup a loop that iterates through each table in result set:

[image: For each loop setup 1]

[image: For each loop storing current table in variable]

Then in your data flow task you can read from one connection / table and write to another:

[image: Data flow task]

Comment: Thanks for that Petar, it looks like a big help. Whereabouts in this process can I generate the dynamic SQL for each table's SELECT?

Comment: It's the second SQL Task - this is where you can produce a list of tables e.g. select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Comment: But I need to create a different SELECT statement for each of the tables I have created on `REP`. Can I do that?

Comment: Are the select statements where you pivot things? And can you pivot on the REP server or is it must to land pivoted data only?

Comment: Well I want the tables which I am creating on the `REP` server to be populated with pre-pivotted data, So I'm not sure where the actual pivotting is taking place? Presumably on the LIVE server

Comment: what about a stored procedure to pivot the data into a staging table on LIVE...then use Petar's template for moving the data to REP?